# ¿me pueden ayudar con este ejercicio de sql?

Tags: sql

Incrementar el precio en un 10% de los productos cuyo valor sea menor a 100.000

```
create table producto(
  cod_producto int primary key,
  desc_producto varchar(20),
  precio_producto int
);

insert into producto values (100,'Televisor Led',198000);

insert into producto values (200,'Refrigerador',127500);

insert into producto values (300,'Cocina',84000);

insert into producto values (400,'Juguera',18000);
```

--se que se hace con un "update" pero nose como puedo incrementar el valor en un 10%

Comment: pues has el intento y si sigues teniendo dudas vienes con una pregunta más concreta

Comment: Has preguntado anteriormente sin exito, necesitas revisar [ask], trata de realizar un [mcve] y a partir de este pregunta dudas.

Answer (score 0):

la consulta quedaria masomenos asi:

```
update producto set precio_producto = precio_producto + (precio_producto*0.1) where precio_producto < 100000
```

Lo que hago es actualizar el campo precio_producto con su mismo valor + el calculo del 10% que seria (precio_producto*0.1) ó ((10*precio_producto)/100) cualquiera es valida, con la condición de que el precio antes de cambiarlo sea menor a 100000.

Ah y debes cambiar el tipo de dato del precio producto a decimal(18,2) por que con la suma puede que obtengas decimales.
Espero te haya servido si es que es lo que buscabas

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Alex.. gracias por la respuesta. En general se pide que quien pregunta muestre que intento, antes de darle una solucion, si no estamos incentivando a que no hagan sus pruebas y solamente esperen a que alguien le resuelva los problemas. Saludos!